# Pulling a Specific Useragent out of Apache Domlogs with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently working on building a Regular Expression which will be able to pull the name of the useragent of a bot visiting a site. So far I've been able to get the Expression to match but it doesn't return the value I'm expecting. Please check the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while (<>)
{
#Remove any unseen whitespace
chomp($_);

my $i = 0;


#Open every file in turn
open(my $domlog, "<", "$_") or die "cannot open file: $!";

#these were used for testing the open/closing of files
#print "Opened $_";
#print "Closed $_";

#for now confirm the file I'm searching through
print "Opened $_\n";

#Adding the name of the domain to the @domaind array for data processing later
push (@domain, $2) if $_ =~ m/(\/usr\/local\/apache\/domlogs\/.*\/)(.*)/;

#search through the currently opened domlog line by line
while (<$domlog>) {

#clear white space again
chomp $_;

#Print the the record in full, then print the IP address of the visitor and what should be the useragent name 
print "$_\n";
print "$1\n $2\n\n" if $_ =~ m/^(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\s(.*)\s.*(\w+[crawl|bot|spider|yahoo|bing|google])?/i;

}

close $domlog;

}
```

I'm not sure if my regex is too greedy or if I'm using the wildcard incorrectly. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

I completely forgot the input as I was worrying about the code here, I ran the script over some domlogs on my server, here are a few of the outputs as well as what I'm getting out of it.

**Input**
188.165.15.208 - - [13/Jan/2015:09:20:49 -0500] "GET /?page_id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"

**output**
188.165.15.208
 - - [13/Jan/2015:09:20:49 -0500] "GET /?page_id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0;

**Input**
180.76.4.26 - - [13/Jan/2015:10:16:24 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8744 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"

**output**
180.76.4.26
 - - [13/Jan/2015:10:16:24 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8744 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT

Comment: The character class can contain only character `[crawl|bot|spider|yahoo|bing|google]` wont be interpretted as you think it would be. Rather as `c` or `r` or `a` etc Provide some sample inputs for better clarity.

Comment: `\s(.*)\s.*`Here the `\s` are useless as the `.*` being greedy will consume all the `\s` if any.

Comment: `\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}` can be simplified as `\d{1,3}(.\d{1,3}){3}`

Comment: `it doesn't return the value I'm expecting` - You should share that value with us. A sample of the log would be useful.

Comment: Your comments "Remove any unseen whitespace" and "clear white space again" are both incorrect. `chomp()` removes the current value of `$/` (usually a newline) from the given string. It has no effect on any other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example expected output I'm only open to guesses what you may want to achieve. But here are some things to point out about your script:

```
push (@domain, $2) if $_ =~ m/(\/usr\/local\/apache\/domlogs\/.*\/)(.*)/;
```

You're already using the `m` operator, with it you can change the delimiting character. Furthermore, there is the `(?:…)` non-matching group but in this case, you don't even need that. Regular expressions in bare always match on `$_` if they aren't used with `=~` so you can get rid of that. In list-context, they're returning the contents of the matching groups. Here now all combined:

```
push @domain, m~/usr/local/apache/domlogs/.*/(.*)~;
```

Now on to your other expression. If things get complicated, you should use the `/x` flag, it raises readability in a great manner.

`.` is a special character in regexes, it matches anything, so you might want to escape that. Also, for the ip-address matching you can make use of `(?:…)`:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

`[…]` matches **characters within the brakets** so your

```
[crawl|bot|spider|yahoo|bing|google]`
```

can be reduced to

```
[abcdeghilnoprstwy|]
```

and would do the same thing, which is clearly not what you want, but stresses, where you went wrong. What you probably wanted is a non-matching group. If you make it optional, it'll likely not match (so get rid of the `?` after the group).

`(?:crawl|bot|spider|yahoo|bing|google)`

So here is what this devil may look combined:

```
if (/^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})                  # $1 - ip address
     \s(.*)\s*                                   # $2 - within spaces
     (\w*(?:crawl|bot|spider|yahoo|bing|google)) # $3 - some bot string
    /xi){                                        # end of regex
  print ("$1\n$2\n$3\n");
}
```

Probably still not what you want but I don't know what that is. You might want to make the group for `$2` non-greedy `(.*?)`. Also maybe escape some of the parentheses if you want to have a match inside of them.

And lastly, take a look at [loghack](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/ApacheLog-Parser/bin/loghack) since somebody might already have done the work for you.

Here are the relevant pieces of documentation (these are `perldoc` pages, so if you have `perldoc` installed on your system, you also can do `perldoc perlretut`):

- [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) a tutorial for regexes.
- [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) the documentation for regexes.
- [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) if you've at least gone through `perlretut` this reference comes in handy.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, using the modified code you provided so far, I pulled the bollowing information: `188.165.15.208 - - [13/Jan/2015:09:20:49 -0500] "GET /?page_id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
188.165.15.208
bot`
I'm trying to pull this information: `188.165.15.208 - - [13/Jan/2015:09:20:49 -0500] "GET /?page_id=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
188.165.15.208
AhrefsBot/5.0;`
so maybe the regex is not quite accurate here.

Comment: You still failed to tell what your expected output is, so there won't be anyone able to tell what the right solution is.

Comment: @JPeck89: If you want the bot name (just a guess, again) you can match with `/\((?:.*?;)*([^;]*(?:b(?:ot|ing)|crawl|yahoo|google|spider)[^;]*);/`. The name will be in `$1`. It uses excluding matching groups `[^;]` to match anything but `;`.